# How does new instances from Auto Scaling group get added to target group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

How do the new instances from the autoscaling group get added to the target group? For example - I have an asg that is running with 2 instances that are added to the target group.  Now, when my asg scales up how do the new instances get added to the target group?  What happens to the old instances that get terminated when asg scales down?  The reason I ask is I don't see an option in the target group to add autoscaling groups. I only see an option to add the instances.

Thank you

Comment: [Attach a load balancer to your Auto Scaling group - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/attach-load-balancer-asg.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Target groups are created
2. ASG is created. TG created in step 2 is associated with ASG
3. Scale in: Instance is terminated. ASG does this. Target group is attached to ASG and aware of this
4. Scale out: Instance is added. ASG does his. Target group is attached to ASG and aware of this